# Add Header and footer to feed display

Tags: views, feeds

I'm using Drupal 7. I have create a feed using views. Is there any way to add header and footer to feed page?

Comment: It does not seem to be possible by design using Views itself: https://www.drupal.org/node/688974 . There is a similar DrupalAnswers question that tackles the issue by creating a custom module: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79868/add-custom-tag-in-rss-xml-header-drupal-7